# Stack Behavior with Math

Tags: java, math, stack

I am adding two very large Integers, up to 125 digits, without the use of the Integer class or the BigInteger class, only java's Stack utility. It just simply loads the two large integers into a stack and then compares each `pop()`.

I initially have a method to load the stacks, A and B from their own `JTextArea.getText()`

```
 public Stack<Integer> loadStack(String numA)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(numA);
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            stack.push(scan.nextInt());
        }
        //System.out.println(stack.toString());
        return stack;
    }
```

and then my method that displays the resulting stack is called `resTF.setText(num.addStacks(stackA, stackB).toString());` where resTF is another JTextArea for the result.

my method that adds takes two `Stack<Integer>`'s

```
public Stack<Integer> addStacks(Stack<Integer> stackA, Stack<Integer> stackB)
    { 
        Stack<Integer> resultStack = new Stack<Integer>();

        while(!stackA.empty() && !stackB.empty())
        {
            try
            {   
                int carry = 0;
                //get the digits to add
                int tokenA = stackA.pop();
                int tokenB = stackB.pop();

                //add them and mod 10
                int result = tokenA + tokenB + carry;
                int resultDigit = result % 10;

                //push the result on to the new stack
                resultStack.push(resultDigit);

                //the updated carry
                carry = result / 10;
                if (carry > 0)
                {
                    resultStack.push(carry);
                }
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(resultStack.toString());
        return resultStack;
    }
```

1: My stack is giving me output such as, `[6, 66]` when adding `555` and `111` when the desired output would be `[6,6,6]` i think? Why is this? because of the way its being read in? I believe i am messing up possibly in the addition.

2: When i type in very very very large numbers like `100000000000000000000000000000000000000` and `200000000000000000000000000000000000000` I get, so I know its my loadStacks method that is cause the issues, particularly the scanning it in. What am i missing?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at GUI.BigNumber.loadStack(BigNumber.java:19)
```

EDIT 1*****

```
public void checkJagged(Stack<Integer> stackA, Stack<Integer> stackB)
    {
        int stackSizeA = stackA.size();
        int stackSizeB = stackB.size();

        if (stackA.size() < stackB.size())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stackSizeB; ++i)
            {
                if (stackA.elementAt(i) == null)
                {
                    stackA.push(0);
                }
            }
        }
        if (stackA.size() > stackB.size())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stackSizeA; ++i)
            {
                if (stackB.elementAt(i) == null)
                {
                    stackB.push(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input processing is causing part of the described problem -- the scanner will read the whole number as one value. Do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < numA.length(); i++) {
  stack.push(Integer.parseInt(numA.substring(i, i + 1));
}
```

The other problem is that you push the carry in the loop. This would result in 1 2 1 2 1 2 for 666 + 666 with a fixed parser. Its' sufficient to add the carry in the loop, and only push the final carry value after the loop. Also, set it to 0 before the loop, so the previous carry is actually added (opposed to be overwritten with 0).

Moreover, you'll need to account for the case where the stacks are of different sizes. Simplest way is to keep going while one stack is not empty, and treat the exhausted stack as containing zeros.

Comment: I see, I have taken all of these things into account and fixed it so everything displays the right numbers and the correct text :) Only issue i have now which isn't really an issue on the stack's fault is i need to preserve the order similar to a queue instead of reversing it. [2. 3. 3.1] where i would like [1, 3, 3, 2]

Comment: You could use an integer array of size (Math.max(stackA.size(), stackB.size()) + 1) as intermediate storage, then build the stack from that (if you have to use stacks, otherwise I'd just use arrays everywhere). Note that storig sigle digits and using object arrays are quite memory inefficient here. You could store multiple digits in each entry without modifying much (basically you'd convert from base 10 to base 1000000 or similar)

Comment: I have editted my question in regards to making sure that both stacks are the same size with the input of 0's if they are not, inside my edit of the original post is that implementation something close? @Stefan Haustein

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you expect `nextInt()`to return only one digit, but it does return all consecutive digits.

You need to consume the textbox contents as `String` and work on the characters.

```
 public Stack<Integer> loadStack(String numA)
 {
     if(numA == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
     char[] chars = numA.toCharArray();
     Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
     for (char c : chars) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
            stack.push((c - '1') < 9 ? (c - '1' + 1) : 0);
     }
     return stack;
 }
```